# Letter Arrow with For Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a homework to make an arrow letter with ***nested for loop in Python***. The goal is to make an arrow that starts with input letter and the input maximum size; for example, input C for letter and 5 for size the output should be like this

```
C
D D
E E E
F F F F
G G G G G
H H H H H
I I I I
J J J
K K
L
```

I'm having a problems with making it starts with the input letter, and make it have maximum for 2 rows. This is what I got so far (since when I change the variable to make it starts with input letter the code is error).

```
letter = (input("What is the starting letter? "))
size = int(input("What is the maximum size of the arrow? Please enter an integer: "))


val = 65
for x in range(0,size):
    for y in range (0,x+1):
        char = chr(val)
        print (char, end = " ")
    val = val + 1
    print()

for x in range(size,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x-1):
        char = chr(val)
        print (char, end = " ")
    val = val + 1
    print()
```

When I run this, it look like this

```
What is the starting letter? C
What is the maximum size of the arrow? Please enter an integer: 5
A 
B B 
C C C 
D D D D 
E E E E E 
F F F F 
G G G 
H H 
I
```

Comment: Perhaps you set `val` to `val = ord(letter)`, instead of 65. I mean, `letter` is not even used anywhere in your code after being set.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why it starts with `A` is because u have `val` set to 65 i.e ascii value for `A`

use

```py
val = ord(letter)
```

instead of

```py
val = 65
```

this should now work as intended

ord - returns the string to its ascii value of the string

Answer (score 1):

The `letter` variable has not been used in the rest of the code. You should do something like:

```py
letter = (input("What is the starting letter? "))
size = int(input("What is the maximum size of the arrow? Please enter an integer: "))


val = ord(letter)
for x in range(0,size):
    for y in range (0,x+1):
        char = chr(val)
        print (char, end = " ")
    val = val + 1
    print()

for x in range(size,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x-1):
        char = chr(val)
        print (char, end = " ")
    val = val + 1
    print()
```

##### Example output

```
What is the starting letter? C
What is the maximum size of the arrow? Please enter an integer: 5
C 
D D 
E E E 
F F F F 
G G G G G 
H H H H 
I I I 
J J 
K
```

Note that, this won't work with an input like `Z` as the character and `4` as the number.

##### Wrong Output

```
What is the starting letter? Z
What is the maximum size of the arrow? Please enter an integer: 4
Z 
[ [ 
\ \ \ 
] ] ] ] 
^ ^ ^ 
_ _ 
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed the point in setting variables, at first. The result is all correct now, and it looks like this

```
letter = (input("What is the starting letter? "))
size = int(input("What is the maximum size of the arrow? Please enter an integer: "))

val = ord(letter)
for x in range(0,size):
    for y in range (0,x+1):
        char = chr(val)
        print (char, end = " ")
    val = val + 1
    print()

for x in range(size,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x):
        char = chr(val)
        print (char, end = " ")
    val = val + 1
    print()
```

changing the `val = 65`  to `val = ord(letter)` and change the`x-1`to `x` to make 2 rows of maximum. Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: This is just to show the power of Python. After the input these two lines with only one `for` loop are all you need: `for line_number, width in enumerate(list(range(1, size+1)) + list(range(size, 0, -1))):` followed by `print(' '.join([chr(ord(letter) + line_number)] * width))`